# Azure: How to Forward PORT to another VM

Tags: azure, port-forwarding, azure-networking

What is the most likely way to forward specific Ports received from a public IP to another internal IP with Azure Mechanismn? Lets asume all machines are REDHAT 7.3 Machines.

1. Working: Using IPTABLES oder other linux internal services to forward some specific ports to another ip. GOT IT.
2. Azure Load Balancer: Refering to [Microsoft Technet Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Port-Mapping-on-new-Azure-Portal/td-p/63181) Bug or Feature? I can use a Load Balancer to reoute a specific Port to another VM. For Example Route Port 443 to another IP to Port 12443. But once you made such rule, any other rule for this Load Balancer is FIXED to the destination IP from the previous rule. The Azure Portal does not allow to select another Desitionation for the Forwarding. Is this a Bug? I added another Rule and tried to change the target destionation for the second url using the azure cli. No exceptions, but it does also not change anything.
3. ??? Another Resource in Azure i could use?

Since I configured Network security groups in Azure, i would like to manage port forwards also in azure not in an Linux. What is best approach for that, or is it not possible?

Seems to be a missing feature? [Azure Feature Request: Basic IP Forwarding](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/13069704-allow-basic-port-forwarding-in-network-security-gr)

Comment: Yep, you can just upvote this idea in feedback forum.